# "Notice: Trying to get property" for nested menu

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, menu

| cID | cPID | cSlug | cName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | hello | H1 |
| 2 | 0 | world | WORLD |
| 3 | 0 | mars | MARS |
| 4 | 1 | people | People |
| 5 | 1 | dogs | Dogs |
| 6 | 3 | cats | Cats:) |

*cPID: Parent ID*

PHP:

```
$getMenuData = $db->table($vtCategories)->getAll();
$menu = [];
foreach ($getMenuData as $row) {
    if ($row->cPID === 0) {
        $menu[$row->cID] = $row;
        $menu[$row->cID]['submenus'] = [];
    } else {
        $menu[$row->cPID]['submenus'][] = $row;
    }
}
foreach ($menu as $item) {
    echo $item->cID . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;    //  <<--- LINE 16
    foreach ($item['submenus'] as $subitem) {
        echo '<br>' . $subitem->cName . '--' . $subitem->cPID . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'cID' of non-object in
> /var/www/clients/client7/web31/web/test1.php on line 16

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$row` is an object, you cannot do `$menu[$row->cID]['submenus']`, because `$menu[$row->cID]` is an object, not an array.

You should use `$menu[$row->cID]->submenus`.

Also, `$row->cPID === 0` is not a good condition because if will not create the "main" entry if cPID is not 0.

You could use `if (!isset($menu[$row->cID])) {` to create main entry if not exist and `if ($row->cPID > 0) {` to add is cPID is defined.

Full code

```php
$menu = [];
foreach ($getMenuData as $row) {
    if (!isset($menu[$row->cID])) {
        $menu[$row->cID] = $row;
        $menu[$row->cID]->submenus = [];
    } 
    if ($row->cPID > 0) {
        $menu[$row->cPID]->submenus[] = $row;
    }
}
foreach ($menu as $item) {
    
    echo $item->cID . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;    //  <<--- LINE 16
    foreach ($item->submenus as $subitem) {
        echo '<br>' . $subitem->cName . '--' . $subitem->cPID . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1<br>
<br>People--1
<br>Dogs--1
2<br>
3<br>
<br>Cats:)--3
```

Comment: Live demo : https://3v4l.org/HEOUW

Comment: Thank you for your help but this time I got one more error. [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/wwCpvxx). So what's wrong with my [array -> `getMenuData`](https://pastebin.com/1ZMB5XTk)?

Comment: I've update the answer. Please check the different `if`. And see the live demo : https://3v4l.org/oO5g9

Comment: Your explanation was enlightening for me. I have seen my mistake. Thank you for your time.